# Tensorflow Lite labels.txt not found

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing a project that includes tensorflow lite models. I have downloaded inception_v4_299_quant_20181026 model but upon searching the folder I have not found the labels.txt. How can I generate the labels.txt on the inception_v4_299_quant_20181026. Developing this on Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I think they all use the [1000 labels](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a) from image net.